# How to make an email pattern that disallow arabic characters

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, arabic

i am not very experienced in Regular Expression so its why i am asking you :)
my question is i use this pattern when i validate Emails.

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zAZ\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

what is it to add to this pattern to disallow Arabic characters ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions **[should not be used to validate emails.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/1379664)**

The correct way to validate an email address is using the `MailAddress` class like this:

```
try 
{
    string address = new MailAddress(address).Address;
} 
catch(FormatException) 
{
    //address is invalid
}
```

---

Regarding the question itself, *after* you see that it is a valid email address - you can **[check for arabic characters](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/48facc69-9506-4146-b1b9-e1f3ef4e0ce7)**.

Comment: This will only work in C#, but not in JavaScript. See the question tags.

Comment: its a very good post you sent me i used this

/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i

Comment: @cimnine He will need to perform Server Side validation either way, and any check he will do in Javascript using RegEx will not be enough.

Comment: @Blachshma One for you. Yet you still did not tell how to check for arabian characters, which was the problem in the first place ;-)

Comment: @Blachshma Oh, sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could do it with a [bracket expression (aka Character Set aka Character Class)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and unicode escapes (available in [javascript](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)):

```
[^\u####-\u%%%%]
```

... where the hashtags (`####`) represent the first arabian character (i.e. the character with the lowest unicode value), and the percent signs (`%%%%`) the last arabian character (i.e. the character with the highest unicode value).

[Wikipedia tells me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode) that there are multiple ranges of arabian characters, so you'd need to repeat the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Use Character Properties:

```
/\p{sc=Arabic}/
```

matches all Arabic characters.

Then inverse the chracters that the expression matches to

```
/[^\p{sc=Arabic}]/
```